# Variadic function parameters and non variadic function of same signiture, which will run?

Tags: java, compilation

I've just tested the following scenario, two functions :

```
// method A
private void make(Object ...objects ){
    System.out.println("varargs make");
}

// method B
private void make(){
    System.out.println("non varargs make");
}
```

with the call `make()`.

If only one of the two methods is present in the code then it is the one being called.
However when both methods are present then only method B is called.

I have two more theoretical questions and one practical..

1) What makes the compiler "favor" B to A ?

2) Is this intentional (standard) or a result of the implementation of the compiler ?

3) Is there a way to "force" the compiler to call method A ?

Comment: The answer to 3. is probably no... Unless you code method B as `make(new Object[0])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) What makes the compiler "favor" B to A ?

The JLS spec.  It favours the most specific match (and has rules as to what that means)

> 2) Is this intentional (standard) or a result of the implementation of the compiler ?

By design.

> 3) Is there a way to "force" the compiler to call method A ?

Give an object array, empty or other wise.

```
make(new Object[0]);
```